# Where the architecture of iOS apps is explained?

Tags: ios, xcode

Could you please point me to the documentation, where the meaning and format of all files inside iOS app source is explained? I'm trying to understand the architecture of iOS applications, behind the UI of Xcode.

Comment: This is too board. One question at a time.

Comment: @BryanChen I made it shorter

Comment: Check out Paul Hegarty's (Stanford University) online course

Comment: unzip an ipa file, ask question if you have problem understand the functionality of a file there. I expect you know what is info.plist and resources files.

Comment: Here you will find all of Apples document that is available to you: https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the extension on the app from ".ipa" to ".zip". Then double-clock to unzip. Examine the unzipped folder's contents.